# Displaying results as soon as they are ready with std::async

Tags: c++, asynchronous

I'm trying to discover asynchronous programming in C++. Here's a toy example I've been using:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <vector>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <random>

// For simplicity
using namespace std;

int called_from_async(int m, int n)
{
    this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(rand() % 1000));
    return m * n;
}

void test()
{
    int m = 12;
    int n = 42;

    vector<future<int>> results;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            results.push_back(async(launch::async, called_from_async, i, j));
        }
    }

    for(auto& f : results)
    {
        cout << f.get() << endl;
    }
}
```

Now, the example is not really interesting, but it raises a question that is, to me, interesting. Let's say I want to display results as they "arrive" (I don't know what will be ready first, since the delay is random), how should I do it?

What I'm doing here is obviously wrong, since I wait for all the tasks in the order in which I created them - so I'll wait for the first to finish even if it's longer than the others.

I thought about the following idea: for each `future`, using `wait_for` on a small time and if it's ready, display the value. But I feel weird doing that:

```cpp
while (any_of(results.begin(), results.end(), [](const future<int>& f){
    return f.wait_for(chrono::seconds(0)) != future_status::ready;
}))
{
    cout << "Loop" << endl;
    for(auto& f : results)
    {
        auto result = f.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
        if (result == future_status::ready)
            cout << f.get() << endl;
    }
}
```

This brings another issue: we'd call `get` several times on some `future`s, which is illegal:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::future_error' 
> what():  std::future_error: No associated state

So I don't really know what to do here, please suggest!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`valid()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/valid) to skip the futures for which you have already called `get()`.

```
bool all_ready;
do {
    all_ready = true;
    for(auto& f : results) {
        if (f.valid()) {
            auto result = f.wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));
            if (result == future_status::ready) {
                cout << f.get() << endl;
            }
            else {
                all_ready = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
while (!all_ready);
```

Comment: Not really a solution. The code still waits for 20ms on each task in the order that they were created. It may create an illusion that results are printed "as soon as" they are available and may be sufficient for simple situations. But try it with 100 tasks, slow ones created first, fast ones last. A real solution is a bit more involved and requires a `mutex`, a `condition_variable`, and some sort of queue for the results.